# Refresh menu on .mouseout

Tags: jquery

I have a menu within a page, I have an active class applied to the relevant menu item in relation to the page.

This active class is reused when another menu item is hovered over, and is removed from the original menu item.

How can I make the menu `<div>` refresh when I .mouseout from #menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $("#menu").mouseout(function(){
      // refresh logic here
    });
});
```

Mouseleave is also an option, depends on your situation. Read Shawn's comment ...

Comment: Any idea how to refresh a single <div>

Comment: Sure, you're going to have to tell us what you mean by refresh tho :)

Comment: Reload the contents (HTML) of the #menu <div>

Comment: You may want to use the mouseleave event instead so you don't run into the problem of mouseout firing when hovering over children of #menu.

Comment: It wil be easier to just make the necesarry changes using jquery (adding and removing classes from your items)